# Google map auto complete call without place details request

Tags: jquery, api, dictionary, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am using google map java script autocomplete on my site

Here is my java script code for rendering google auto autocomplete

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY}}&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {

 var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
 };

 var input = document.getElementById('city');
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
  autocomplete.setFields(['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']); 
}
initialize(); 

</script>
```

and html code is

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" required="" value="" placeholder="City" autocomplete="off">
```

In billing section , I am getting charged for 
  1.Places API Autocomplete without Places Details 
  2.Places API Places Details

I never used place details request anywhere in my site .How this request is fired ?.
 Is it calling automatically after autocomplete request? How can i prevent it? 
My site uses geolocation api to convert address into lat and long coordinates. Will it use place details api ?

How can I call google map autocomplete without firing  place details request

Comment: AFAIK, Places Details is when you use the `getDetails()` method of the Places Service or direct requests to the [Places Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) via the Places API. Are you not using this on another part of your website or a different website?

Comment: not used  it in other sites/other parts in my site @MrUpsidown

Comment: Still that's what it's supposed to be about. You could always create a new API key, revoke the one you are using now, implement the new one, and see what happens. The code you posted above is not supposed to count a place details request. If these requests are still counted after trying that, you might want to contact Google directly.

Comment: I will check that.will gecode lat and long conversion use place details ? @MrUpsidown

Comment: Maybe a [reverse geocode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) request. Not sure though.

Comment: I suspect the use of the `.setFields` method.

Answer (score 6):

Fixed the  issue. A PlaceService.GetPlaceDetails is called automatically every time you select or click an Autocomplete Suggestion even if you have no autocomplete.getPlace() function in your code.
Additionally, using the Autocomplete Widget, when the user picks a prediction, the widget will call Place Details for you, so that a full Place result will be available when you call autocomplete.getPlace() upon the place_changed event.
If you don't want Place Details to be called, use {placeIdOnly: true} when initializing the widget.

Answer (score 6):

placeIdOnly [is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions.fields) as of January 15, 2019, and fields can be set in the Autocomplete constructor, this code worked for me and stopped the autocomplete from calling the places details request:

```
 autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            document.getElementById('Details_Location'), { fields: ["place_id"] });
```

Comment: Hi, how do you extract geometry.location.lat() and geometry.location.lng() without calling getPlace() and only with the autocomplete object?

Comment: where I should write this code in the drupal project?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem.
I try

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        document.getElementById('Details_Location'), { fields: ["place_id"] });
```

For getting geometry.location.lat() and geometry.location.lng(), you can use separate [google.maps.Geocoder()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview), with string from autocomplete.
[google.maps.Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview) is cheaper than Places Details.

Code something like:

```
autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", setMapCenter);

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function setMapCenter() {
    data = {
        address: autocomplete_input_value
    };
    geocoder.geocode( data, function(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            // var map = new google.maps.Map();
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        } else {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```